# show loader using Higher Order Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

I could show the loader icon using conditions in each containers but when using higher order component i could not show it. I have posted my code below. I have used immutable.js, redux-saga. Below is the code i have coded which is not working

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  logs: selectLogs(),
  logState: selectAllLogState(), #has requesting flag in it
  dialog: selectDialog()
});

class Logs extends React.PureComponent {}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  Loader("requesting")(Logs)
);

export const selectAllLogState = () => state => state.get("logs");

export const selectLogs = () => state => state.getIn(["logs", "logs"]);

const Loader = prop => WrappedComponent => {
  return class Loader extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return this.props[prop]
        ? <div className="earth-spinning">
            <img
              src={EarthSpinning}
              alt="spinner"
              style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}
            />
          </div>
        : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
};

export default Loader;

const initialState = fromJS({
  requesting: false,
  deleted: false,
  response: {},
  logs: {},
  error: null
});

function showLogs(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGS_FETCH_REQUEST:
      return state.set("requesting", true);
    case LOGS_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .set("requesting", false)
        .set("logs", fromJS(action.logs.data.dataList, idReviver));
    case LOGS_FETCH_FAILURE:
      return state.set("error", action.error).set("requesting", false);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default showLogs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spread all keys from your `selectLogs()` call like

`createStructuredSelector({
    ...selectLogs(),
    logState: selectAllLogState(),
});`

or set this prop explicitly:

`const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    logs: selectLogs(),
    requesting: selectLogs().requesting
});`

Comment: but selectLogs has only logs object not the requesting flag. The reason i fetch only the logs object in the selector is due to other flags like response, error, deleted etc which are not needed anytime

Comment: ok but you need somehow to obtain this `requesting` value from store in your `mapStateToProps` function

Comment: Loader('logState')(Logs) worked but the log page is continuously rendering.

Comment: yes, because when request is done you're changing `requesting` flag inside `logs` reducer